# Automation Anywhere SQL results

Tags: sql, sql-server, resultset, is-empty, automationanywhere

I am trying to capture if my SQL Query have 0 rows or multiple rows. If it has 0 rows then I will insert, if 1 will perform an update, if > 1 will perform additional analysis.

Is there a way I can see if my query resulted in x results or no results in automation anywhere?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your query, sample data and expected results as your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `if exists` and `if not exists` and check if rows exists or not, or even if there are multiple before doing the insert.

Here is a simple example using `if not exists` where if the row doesn't exist on `dbo.Table` it will insert a row. If it already exists then the ID will be logged to an Error table.

```
declare @InsertID int = 5, @Name nvarchar(max) = 'some name'
if ((select count(1) from dbo.Table where ID = @InsertID) > 1) -- detect error; more than one record for an id
begin
    insert into dbo.Error (ErrorID, ErrorDate)
    select @InsertID, getdate()
end
else if not exists (select 1 from dbo.Table where ID = @InsertID) -- no record exists for ID, insert it
begin
    insert into dbo.Table (ID, Name)
    select @InsertID, @Name
else if exists (select 1 from dbo.Table where ID = @InsertID)  -- update the single record
begin
    update dbo.Table set Name = @Name where ID = @InsertID 
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Only our DBAs can create stored procedures; however,  I used the solution you suggested in another fashion and it Worked!  I did a count on the id of the table and counted the rows returned.  Then I assigned the $Dataset Column(1)$ to a variable, then did a loop on $Dataset Column(1)$, then did an If , Else If, Else to check if  the result was 0,1, or greater.  Thank You!  Kudos to you for sparking the idea for me to solve.  KUDOS to you!

Comment: @Murita, I updated the answer so its just a script and not a stored procedure. Let me know if you have any questions or if this works for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A2019 returns the results of a SQL Query as a table...

You could have an if statement right after your query which checks to see if the row count of the returned table is > 0 then take action accordingly.

[image]